# DynamoDB table description using ruby script

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, amazon-dynamodb

I am new to Ruby on Rail with DynamoDb. So i was trying to get table description using script but nowhere i find this . Please help.
I can do below by iterating through out tables as below but i wanted proper SDK use to find this.

```
aws dynamodb describe-table --table-name {t.name}
```

Comment: If you're looking for something like `schema`, take a look at [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkforruby/api/Aws/DynamoDB/Table.html#attribute_definitions-instance_method)

Answer (score 0):

You're welcome to Ruby.

You can use the [Client#describe_table](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-ruby/v3/api/Aws/DynamoDB/Client.html#describe_table-instance_method)  method.

> Returns information about the table, including the current status of
>   the table, when it was created, the primary key schema, and any
>   indexes on the table.
>
> If you issue a DescribeTable request immediately after a CreateTable
>   request, DynamoDB might return a ResourceNotFoundException. This is
>   because DescribeTable uses an eventually consistent query, and the
>   metadata for your table might not be available at that moment. Wait
>   for a few seconds, and then try the DescribeTable request again.

```
# This example describes the Music table.

resp = client.describe_table({
  table_name: "Music", 
})

# resp.to_h outputs the following:
{
  table: {
    attribute_definitions: [
      {
        attribute_name: "Artist", 
        attribute_type: "S", 
      }, 
      {
        attribute_name: "SongTitle", 
        attribute_type: "S", 
      }, 
    ], 
    creation_date_time: Time.parse("1421866952.062"), 
    item_count: 0, 
    key_schema: [
      {
        attribute_name: "Artist", 
        key_type: "HASH", 
      }, 
      {
        attribute_name: "SongTitle", 
        key_type: "RANGE", 
      },
    ], 
    provisioned_throughput: {
      number_of_decreases_today: 1, 
      read_capacity_units: 5, 
      write_capacity_units: 5, 
    }, 
    table_name: "Music", 
    table_size_bytes: 0, 
    table_status: "ACTIVE", 
  }, 
}
```